# Javascript clock update on the minute help?

Tags: javascript, time

ok i have a cool digital clock and javascript but i cant get it to update every minute, help?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('digital.ttf');
}
html {
    font-family: "Digital";
    font-size: 130px;
}

#clock {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function getClockTime()
{
   var now    = new Date();
   var hour   = now.getHours();
   var minute = now.getMinutes();
   if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12;      }
   if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;             }
   if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
   var timeString = hour +
                    ':' +
                    minute
   return timeString;
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000;" onload="init();">
<p id="clock" align="center">hi</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
var clockTime = getClockTime();
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = clockTime;
</script>
<script type=text/javascript>

function init()
{
    getClockTime();
    window.setInterval(getClockTime,30000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('digital.ttf');
}
html {
    font-family: "Digital";
    font-size: 130px;
}

#clock {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function getClockTime()
{
   var now    = new Date();
   var hour   = now.getHours();
   var minute = now.getMinutes();
   var second = now.getSeconds();
   if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12;      }
   if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;             }
   if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute; }
   var timeString = hour +
                    ':' +
                    minute + 
                    ':' +
                    second
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = timeString;
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000;" onload="init();">
<p id="clock" align="center">hi</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
var clockTime = getClockTime();

</script>
<script type=text/javascript>

function init()
{
    getClockTime();
    setInterval(getClockTime,1000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw I added seconds to see whether it was working - I didn't have all day to wait for minutes :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are better off to use consecutive setTimeout calls and calcualte the time to wait each time. setInterval is not guaranteed to run at exactly the time you specify, so the clock will slowly drift. Also, if the user doesn't start it exactly on a whole minute, the clock will update out of sync with the system clock.

A modified init function is below that will call the clock setting function about 5ms after the next whole minute each and every time.

```
 function init()
{
    var interval = (60 - (new Date()).getSeconds()) * 1000 + 5;
    getClockTime();
    setTimeout(init,interval);
}
```

Comment: its ok because the way i use right now is working because it does it on the second but i do see the time on my computer change before the html clock so let me give yours a try

Comment: For updates each second, use: interval = 1050 - now.getMilliseconds();

Comment: Can you explain how the interval calculation works.

Comment: @JoshuaUchennaAmaju—it is intended to set the timeout to run just after the next full second. It may not due to the system being busy on other tasks, but it should be close.

Answer (score 1):

This line does nothing as you never accept the return value :

```
return timeString;
```

Instead use that to set the value of your

```
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = timeString;
```

Comment: In the init function the return value isn't used, but elsewhere it is.

Comment: this makes it so the change over laps the last time

Answer (score 1):

A nifty regex will do the trick. Do, however, understand that the functions setTimeout and setInterval are highly unreliable for correctly managing time.

```
$('#clock').ready(function(){
    var updateClock = function(){
        var time = (new Date()).toString().match(/ (\d\d:\d\d):\d\d/);
        $('#clock').text(time[1]);
    };
    setInterval(function(){
        updateClock();
    },60000);
    updateClock();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for react with hooks.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useTime() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    function getTime() {
      let interval = (60 - new Date().getSeconds()) * 1000 + 5;
      setTime(new Date());
      setTimeout(getTime, interval);
    }
    getTime();
  }, []);

  return time;
}
```

Comment: You should use `clearTimeout` on useEffect cleanup

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

1. You are updating the clock every 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds). Is that intentional?
2. getClockTime will be called on the interval. Put `document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = timeString;` as the last line of your function, and you should be good to go.

Comment: this makes it so the change over laps the last time

Answer (score 0):

Added meridiem and post meridiem, fixed bug with seconds not having a preceding zero while less than 10 to @Rob 's answer

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: Digital;
    src: url('digital.ttf');
}
html {
    font-family: "Digital";
    font-size: 130px;
}

#clock {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function getClockTime()
{
   var now      = new Date();
   var hour     = now.getHours();
   var minute   = now.getMinutes();
   var second   = now.getSeconds();
   var meridiem = "AM";

   if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12; $meridiem = "PM" }
   if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12;                         }
   if (minute < 10) { minute = "0" + minute;             }
   if (second < 10) { second = "0" + second;             }
   var timeString = hour +
                    ':' +
                    minute + 
                    ':' +
                    second +
                    ' ' +
                    meridiem
   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = timeString;
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000;" onload="init();">
<p id="clock" align="center">hi</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
var clockTime = getClockTime();

</script>
<script type=text/javascript>

function init()
{
    getClockTime();
    setInterval(getClockTime,1000);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod)
```

Comment: Reloading the page is kind of a hack, not really a fix. He's using setInterval, so he doesn't want the page to refresh.